# Big-O Time Complexity of Nested Loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, nested, time-complexity, big-o

Can someone please tell me what is the Time Complexity of the following nested loop:

```
 for(i=1;i<n;i+=i)
 {
    for(j=1;j<n;j*=j)
       //O(1)
 }
```

According to me it would be O(log(n)*log(log(n))
As the outer loop would run log(n) times as we are effectively multiplying i by 2 every iteration.
And in the inner loop we are squaring the loop counter j in every iteration.
So the final complexity is the product of these two.
Is this correct or is there some other answer.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: `for(j=1;j<n;j*=j)` – this should be **O(infinity)** because `j` will never increase (1 times 1 is still 1). Perhaps you meant e.g. `j=2` as the initial condition? (If this is a homework question, it is probably a trick question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the complexity is `O(log2(n) * log2(log2(n)))`.

The index `j` of the inner loop follow the recurrence relation `j(k) = j(k-1)^2`, that is, `j(k) = j(0)^(2^k)` (proof by induction). Let assume `j(0) = 2` (not `1`, because otherwise you would loop indefinitely).

Therefore, the number of iterations `k` of the inner loop verifies

```
    j(k) >= n
<=> 2^(2^k) >= n
 => k >= log2(log2(n))
```

The number of iteration of the outer loop is >= `log2(n)`.